# Number of Images in Training and Test sets of tfds.load()

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I just want to know if the total number of images in train_data are 60000 or 10000. I tried train_data.shape() but it just returns

```
DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}
```

Please let me know how can I know the number of images.

```
(train_data, test_data), metadata = tfds.load(name = 'mnist',
                                              split = ['train', 'test'],                                      
                                              with_info = True,)
```

Comment: What exactly is `tfds`? Please include the relevant imports.

Answer (score 1):

Given your syntax:

```
(train_data, test_data), metadata = tfds.load(name = 'mnist',
                                              split = ['train', 'test'],                                      
                                              with_info = True)
```

The option `with_info=True` returns the additional info, which is captured by the 2nd variable `metadata` in your case.

Hence, the size of `train_data` and `test_data` can simply be checked as follows:

`print(metadata)`

Further info: `print(train_data.shape)` will not work as it's not numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
    builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
    info = builder.info
    print(info)
```

Output:

```
tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
    name='mnist',
    version=3.0.1,
    description='The MNIST database of handwritten digits.',
    homepage='http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/',
    features=FeaturesDict({
        'image': Image(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.uint8),
        'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=10),
    }),
    total_num_examples=70000,
    splits={
        'test': 10000,
        'train': 60000,
    },
    supervised_keys=('image', 'label'),
    citation="""@article{lecun2010mnist,
      title={MNIST handwritten digit database},
      author={LeCun, Yann and Cortes, Corinna and Burges, CJ},
      journal={ATT Labs [Online]. Available: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist},
      volume={2},
      year={2010}
    }""",
    redistribution_info=,
)
```

From the info metadata you can extract information with the following code:

```
info.features
```

Output:

```
FeaturesDict({
    'image': Image(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.uint8),
    'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=10),
})
```

---

Number of classes, label names:

```
print(info.features["label"].num_classes)
print(info.features["label"].names)
```

Output:

```
10
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

---

Shapes, data types:

```
print(info.features.shape)
print(info.features.dtype)
print(info.features['image'].shape)
print(info.features['image'].dtype)
```

Output:

```
{'image': (28, 28, 1), 'label': ()}
{'image': tf.uint8, 'label': tf.int64}
(28, 28, 1)
<dtype: 'uint8'>
```

---

Split information:

```
print(info.splits)
```

Output:

```
{'test': <tfds.core.SplitInfo num_examples=10000>, 'train': <tfds.core.SplitInfo num_examples=60000>}
```

Available splits:

```
print(list(info.splits.keys()))
```

Output:

```
['test', 'train']
```

And some more. You can see the above examples and more on the tensorflow website @ https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview